# Use Python Match object in string with backreferences

Tags: python, regex

Does Python have a capability to use a Match object as input to a string with backreferences, eg:

```
match = re.match("ab(.*)", "abcd")
print re.some_replace_function("match is: \1", match) // prints "match is: cd"
```

You could implement yourself using usual string replace functions, but I'm sure the obvious implementation will miss edge cases resulting in subtle bugs.

Comment: Was there anything in the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `re.sub` (instead of `re.match`) to search and replace strings.

To use back-references, the best practices is to use raw strings, e.g.: `r"\1"`, or double-escaped string, e.g. `"\\1"`:

```
import re

result = re.sub(r"ab(.*)", r"match is: \1", "abcd")
print(result)
# -> match is: cd
```

But, if you already have a [Match Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) , you can use the `expand()` method:

```
mo = re.match(r"ab(.*)", "abcd")
result = mo.expand(r"match is: \1")
print(result)
# -> match is: cd
```